# MySQL search in jsonarray with integer element

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a json_array [1, 2, 3], and I want to find out where the element '1' is. So I use "select json_search(json_array(1,2,3), 'all', '1')", but the result is always null, different from my expectation '$[0]'. But I can solve it by quoting each element like ["1", "2", "3"]. I want to know how can I search integer directly from a json_array.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` is not a valid JSON array. You require quotes around the string, for it to be a valid JSON array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) says:

> JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path] ...])
>
> Returns NULL if any of the json_doc, search_str, or path arguments are
>   NULL; no path exists within the document; or search_str is not found.

So I guess that you have to add the path argument, but I would have to research that.

Your json_array should be okay:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(1,2,3);
+-------------------+
| JSON_ARRAY(1,2,3) |
+-------------------+
| [1, 2, 3]         |
+-------------------+
```